# Tfs 2012 - Visual Studio 2010 ultimate use

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate version and would like to use it with Team Foundation Server 2012. Is the native VS 2010 Team explorer enough or should I install something else to fully support the new Team foundation Server 2012?

Answer (score 3):

VS 2010 will natively connect to an *on premises* installation of TFS 2012 and it will be able to do all of the things that it could do with a TFS 2010 server.  There are a few features new to TFS 2012 (like local workspaces) that are only available if you have a VS 2012 client.

If you want to connect to tfspreview.com (TFS's new hosted service) then you will need the VS 2010 hosting GDR: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=39070

Comment: Hi Taylor, that' s great, don' t need to install anything else so, as I am not going to use local workspace and tfspreview, does it fully support the agile scrum stuffs, as this is why I am planning to use tfs 2012 ?

Comment: You should be able to do all of the agile/scrum stuff from the web so I will say yes.  I can't think of any of those experiences that occur in VS but if there are some they may not work 100%.

Comment: I tried out team explorer in Visual Studio 2010, doesn' t want to create a project in tfs2012, where as same step in Visual Studio 2012 do the job (I have upgrade by the way Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server 2012 Compatibility GDR and installed the SP1), I guess that there are something else in order for it to able to create new project...

Comment: There are some features that you require Team Explorer 2012. One of those is creating new Team Projects.

Comment: @dtjmsy you can create the Team Projects using TFS 2012's Team Web Access.